# Dnn Menu NodeSelector Issues

Tags: html, dotnetnuke

I am having some issues trying to get this working as my director wants it to work.

We are doing two different top navigations for our DNN website.

I was able to set it up the second one like this;

```
<dnn:MENU ID="MENU1" MenuStyle="BootstrapMenu" runat="server" IncludeNodes="Is Chartwell Right for You?,Culture,Opportunities,Find Your Role,Rewards,Volunteer" IncludeHidden="true" >
```

This works great as long as the pages and folders are on the root level to the rest of the website.

Is there a way to do this so that all the pages and folders are inside an already existing folder?

What we want is that all the items in the IncludeNodes list exist inside the careers folder.

so can we do like this

folder one/folder two/pages

/careers/Culture/page 1, page 2, page 3

/careers/Opportunities/page 1, page 2, page 3

I am trying to use NodeSelector but it is not letting me set it up to work this way.

Comment: I don't exactly follow what you want. Are you trying to put a "secondary" navigation on the site, and control the "level" of what it displays?

Comment: Yes the issue with the way I have done it shown above has to do with the URL showing up in the input box. 

On the live site it is showing that all the inside the careers folder. 

Like this 

http://chartwell.com/careers/your-c...-chartwell 

The way I am doing it with the includenodes looks like this; 

/opportunities/recruitment-process 

We want it to look like this; 

/careers/opportunities/recruitment-process

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/xqyixkkjn/ 

Is it possible to show the everything in the careers folder on the navigation and the other items in that folder only using nodeselector?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NodeSelector to target a specific level. Typically you will target root, or the Parent of the current page. You can also target the current page's children with CurrentChildren

If you haven't seen this yet, be sure to check it out
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/ddrmenu-reference-guide

Comment: Thanks it seems like any time I put something else in the menu like this NodeSelector="CurrentChildren" 'it just breaks on and does not show me anything am I missing something? The whole thing is very confusing to me.

Comment: I have played around with this as well NodeSelector="*,0,0" with the same issue. Is there some kind of tool that I can use to understand what nodes I am trying to do point to?

Comment: No tools that I know of.